# Case When Condition doesn't run correctly when i read from user (PLSQL, Anonymous Block)

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run my code it seems to go through every case condition, no matter the statement inside it.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- I read from the user a simple integer and if he enters the 0 value, I would like to end the program and exit the `loop`.

What happens when I run the program:

- Enters every `when` statement of `case`

Run example:

1. The program asks the user for an integer (0/1/2/3)
2. User enters 0 (the program must exit and break the loop)
3. Asks for City details (line 32)

I haven't tried to enter the city details and continue on running the program

The code I developed:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

declare
    poli_name poli.name%type;
    poli_lat poli.lat%type;
    poli_lon poli.lon%type;
    counter int :=1;

    cursor poli_c is select name,lat,lon from poli;

    number_of_cities int;

    epilogi number;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Select 1 To Enter Details');
    dbms_output.put_line('Select 2 To View All The Details');
    dbms_output.put_line('Select 3 To Run Group Algorithm');
    dbms_output.put_line('Select 0 To Exit The Programm');

    epilogi:=&Epilogi;

    loop
        case epilogi
            when 0 then
                dbms_output.putline('Exiting Programm...');
                exit;
            when 1 then
                name_c := &Enter_City_Name; --line 32
                lat := &Enter_City_Lat;
                lon := &Enter_City_Lon;

                if lon >= -180 and lon <= 180 and lat >= -90 and lat <= 90 then
                    select count(id) into number_of_cities from poli;

                    if number_of_cities  <= 15 then
                        insert into poli values(counter,name_c,lat,lon);
                        dbms_output.putline('City Successfully Added');  
                    else
                        dbms_output.putline('Cities Can Not Be More Than 15');
                    end if;
                else 
                    dbms_output.putline('Wrong Longitude Or Latidute Values');
                end if;
            when 2 then
                open poli_c;
                fetch poli_c into poli_name,poli_lat,poli_lon;
                dbms_output.put_line('Onoma Polis:'||poli_name);
                dbms_output.put_line('Latidute '||poli_name||': '||poli_lat);
                dbms_output.put_line('Longtidute '||poli_name||': '||poli_lon);
                close poli_c;
            when 3 then
                null;
            else
                dbms_output.put_line('Wrong input - try again...');
        end case;

        counter := counter+1;
        epilogi := &Epilogi;
    end loop;
end;
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? What might that be? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure you understood what you saw. Your block was never EXECUTED. Substitution variables (those that begin with `&`) are replaced with user-provided values by SQL\*Plus, or whatever interface you are using (SQL Developer, Toad etc.) **before** sending the code - with the substitutions completed, for **ALL** the variables - to the PL/SQL engine for parsing and then for execution. You provide the first value, for &Epilogi, then SQL\*Plus continues to ask you for values for the other substitution variables. Your code never ENTERS the CASE statement because it doesn't even start execution!

Comment: is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Not really; pl/sql is not meant for interaction with the user. You need an additional layer to take care of that. In a Comment to one of the Answers, Steven Feuersteins suggests an ApEx page. Or whatever other application you may be familiar with, that lets you create a user interface. That's not what pl/sql is for.

Answer (score 0):

&Var is  a substitution variable.

&Epilogi,&Enter_City_Name,   &Enter_City_Lat, &Enter_City_Lon - they all set before the script is executed and passed to it.

So case is working properly , but all variables must be set prior to execution. 
For instance , even in the following case you will need to provide value.

```
declare 
var1 int;

begin
    return;
    dbms_output.put_line('Unreachable code');
    var1 := &v1;


end;
```

Comment: so , is there any way i can avoid  setting values?(although i'm breaking the loop it still asks for values, this is so weird)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible inside the loop - substitution variables as their name implies passed to plsql engine prior to execution.  PLSQL is not interactive - you need to use some other language around it.  It may give you some ideas : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interactive_pl_sql_user_input.htm

Comment: More precisely - `case` doesn't work at all (not properly, not improperly) - because execution never even begins. The `case` statement is never executed, because **nothing** is ever executed - the OP abandoned the attempt before all substitution variables were given values.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that in Postgres `CASE .. WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ...` is an expression and not a statement. As such it is expected that it must be used wherever an expression is valid, i.e. assignment, return, etc ...

*EDIT: 
Genuine mistake, PLSQL vs PGSQL .. The Oracle variant is typically presented with the slash (PL/SQL) which led me to confusion
*

Comment: i understand, but in my example the value 0 doesn't stop the program from running, all &Something initializations run no matter of `exit` or `return` that might have been before it.

Comment: Well, I never used `CASE ...` in a context of a statement (as in your example), but I guess PG is getting confused (or simply ignores the CASE... altogether) and executes the rest of the code in between .. 
This is just a wild guess though .. 
Try hardcoding all values and if you see no difference, perhaps this is the reason

Comment: i've tried it with `IF  ELSE` but the outcome is the same

Comment: Why Postgres ? Question is about pl/sql (Oracle), not pl/pgsql (Postgres) .

Comment: Indeed the question is about pl/sql Oracle

Comment: Indeed the only tab is `plsql`, the title says PLSQL, so this Answer will not help anyone. Downvote from me, but it would be best to delete it.

Comment: Filippos, is your only option for soliciting user input the command line SQL*Plus or whatever else you are using? It would make SO much more sense to write a stored procedure that accepts inputs as in parameters and returns data as out parameters. Then you could invoke it from within, say, an Application Express page (apex.oracle.com). Isolating your business logic from I/O will greatly clean up your logic and make it easier to debug and maintain your code.

Comment: indeed, that's what i was going to try next, my teacher in the university said that we have to create a project like this, read from the user his option and continue on like a C program, im thinking about a procedure ,that stores the date into a table, that will run when the user presses 1,but i don't know if it's going to fix my problem...

Comment: if i were to create a project that simply calculates in which center each city will be (based on long and lat) i would write it in Java...with a simple GUI...but in order to succeed in my course, it has to be in PL/SQL using SQLDeveloper